# Необособление деепричастного оборота внутри ряда однородных членов предложения

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены, деепричастный-оборот

**Весело, игриво и() будто бы все осознав, подмигнула мне помощница.**

Можно ли в данном случае «будто бы все осознав» подогнать под вопрос «как?» и не отделять его запятой от «весело» и «игриво»? Или так даже нужно поступить?

Comment: @М_Г _Мне кажется,_ что вопрос лучше озаглавить так: "Однородные члены. **Необособление** (слитно) деепричастного оборота". У Розенталя: Обособление или необособление… (п. 7) http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Запятая после союза И не ставится:**

*Весело, игриво и будто бы все осознав, подмигнула мне помощница.*

1) **Пояснение ответа:**

Это обособленный обстоятельственный ряд, в который входят **однородны**е обстоятельства, выраженные наречиями и деепричастным оборотом. Союз  БУДТО БЫ относится к деепричастному обороту.

Деепричастный оборот в данном случае по значению приравнивается к наречиям (отвечает на вопрос как?)

Запятая перед **замыкающим союзом И** не ставится.

**После союза И запятая также не ставится**, так как деепричастный оборот внутри ряда не обособляется. Но в то же время весь однородный ряд является обособленным, поэтому стоит запятая в конце деепричастного оборота.

2) **Дополнительный материал** (описание подобных конструкций у Розенталя)

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

6) если деепричастный оборот или одиночное деепричастие выступает в качестве однородного члена предложения с необособленным обстоятельством: Алёша длинно и как-то прищурив глаза посмотрел на Ракитина (Дост.); Клим Самгин шагал по улице **бодро и не уступая дорогу встречным людям** (М. Г.);   Дворник **с недоумением и нахмурясь** разглядывал Раскольникова (Дост.); Он **долго и нимало не стесняясь подробностями** объяснял, почему именно монашек мог быть родителем Иванушки (М. Г.);

Но для смыслового **выделения** или для выражения попутного **пояснения** сочетание наречия с одиночным деепричастием или с деепричастным оборотом может обособляться: **Тихо и как бы капельку побледнев**, проговорила Катерина Ивановна (Дост.);

**Комментарий:**

Таким образом, как мы  видим из примеров у Розенталя, весь однородный ряд, который заканчивается деепричастием или деепричастным оборотом, может быть как обособленным, так и необособленным.

Обособление ряда во многом определяется **структурой** предложения и проверяется **интонацией**.

Сравнить: *Остановив Власову, он **одним дыханием и не ожидая ответов** закидал её трескучими и сухими словами (М. Г.)*;

Но: ***Одним дыханием и не ожидая ответов***, он закидал её трескучими и сухими словами.

Comment: Запятая не ставится (ответ исправлен).

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено.

Comment: _Союз КАК БУДТО относится к деепричастному обороту._ В предложении нет такого союза. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/143777/Будто